# Insert html pages into wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have an html site with a page of info for each county in the US. I want to convert this into a new wordpress site. I can do this one by one but my issue comes when I have mass changes to affiliate code or common text. I would have to got to each page and manually change it. but with over 3000 pages it would be way to time consuming. I dont want to use Iframes but would like to know if there is a way to call the html pages into the wordpress page that makes sense seo wise.

I am open to creating a page for each county or have one page with text or buttons on it with each county listed and when clicked will insert the info below. I know alot about static html coding but am new to php.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want Iframes, I think there only remain two options. I don't know if they will work in WordPress though.

**1. PHP Include**

With the very simple PHP include() statement, you can include the old html files in your new website. If you have a HTML-file for example, name your file `yourname.php` and add this in the position you want your old page to appear:

```
<?php include(path_to_old_page/name.html); ?>
```

This will include the full old page, but the file needs to be on the same server.

**2. AJAX**

With JavaScript you can perform XHTTP-requests to load files from the server. This is easiest when using jQuery. Here you can use the `$(selector).load(path_to_old_page/name.html)` statement. This will load the file in the HTML elements to which the selector applies.

(The selector works the same as CSS selectors, see the w3schools page for more)

This will also include the full old page, when it is on the same server

Comment: would I add this code to the wp page using the text tab

Comment: Sorry, but i sincery dont know. I do not have any experience with WordPress. If you are coding the website this might help, otherwise i will delete my answer cause its useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your static pages in WordPress as well. Like if you want to create a new county named "example" you can create new WordPress page named "example" by entering title " example" .... now come to content. Just copy page content (only "example" county related html code from your static website) and place that code inside newly created WordPress "example" page. Make sure you add this html content inside 'text' tab in editor. Your page will be created with all your existing data ... now you can view this page and can use this page's URL where ever you want.